# How to add checked Item from Listview into arrayList from adapter and send to activity

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, listview, adapter

Sorry if my english is bad. This is my first time post a question. I create an app for ordering. I have a adapter that show data from database in form of listview. I have a button to add product into array and the item that add into array is only listview that has been checked.
My question is:

1. How to add checked item into array and send it into activity
2. I need to send 3 data that is id, quntity and price

this is my adapter:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

     val inflater = myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as
      LayoutInflater
     val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_product, parent, false)

     val arridProduct= arrayListOf<String>()
     val arrTotalPrice = arrayListOf<String>()
     val arrQuantity = arrayListOf<String>()
     val textNamaProduct = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewNamaProduct)
     val textHargaProduct = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewHargaProduct)

     var checkBoxAddProduct1 = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBoxAddProduct)

      =view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAddToCart)

     var numPickerQuantity1 = view.findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.numberPickerQuantity)


      checkBoxAddProduct1.setOnClickListener {


          if(checkBoxAddProduct1.isChecked){

              arridProduct.add(product[position].idProduct)
              arrTotalPrice.add(product[position].price.toString())
              arrQuantity.add(numPickerQuantity1.value.toString())

              numPickerQuantity1.maxValue=10
              numPickerQuantity1.minValue=1

          }
          else{


              arridProduct.remove(product[position].idProduct)
              arrTotalPrice.remove(product[position].price.toString())
              arrQuantity.remove(numPickerQuantity1.value.toString())
              numPickerQuantity1.maxValue=0
              numPickerQuantity1.minValue=0
          }

     }

     textNamaProduct.text=product[position].nama.toString()
     textHargaProduct.text=product[position].price.toString()

     return view
 } }
```

and this is the example of the display [image: picture]

Comment: 1.How to add checked item into array and send it into activity :- add Boolean variable in model class like isChecked and than on click pass the status of checkbox in isChecked variable after that add this model to array list.
2.I need to send 3 data that is id, quantity and price :-
You have to create model class and store data like id, quantity and price in that class after that add the model in array list and than pass in Listview or another activity

Comment: ok thanks for the information but i still confuce how can i use add button because my add button is in activity but the process is in adapter